# How to scale a table before sending it to @media print CSS

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have multiple dynamic html tables that I need to print. I would like to use the .offsetWidth() function to get my tables width and then set it's scale factor or width before sending it to window.print() and my custom CSS print. Ultimate goal is to have all tables width scaled to fit printing page. How can I resize/change width/scale my table correctly to fit a normal page print?

here is my printing CSS:

```
body, .container, html {
height: 100%;
width: 8.5in !important;
max-width: 8.5in !important;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
page-break-inside: avoid;
background-color: white !important;}
```

and here is my psuedo code for what I believe is I need to do...

```
var table = document.getElementById('MainTable')
var tableSize = table.offsetWidth
if (tableSize > someValue) {
    // scale down  to correct size
}
else {
// scale up to correct size
}
```

Do I need to convert my pixel results to inches before hand? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are differences in the JS logic or just the sizing? You may find the Chrome dev tools useful to force print preview state and manipulate the styling of your table: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/print-preview. Also this might be helpful: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/ You can still use px, but be sure to check how it will look on the page with the print preview.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found the answer I was looking for. I needed to reset the CSS and expand my table to fit the desired div. easily done in one line of code.

```
    $(table).css({ 'table-layout': '', 'width':'100%'});
```